# Compare the pixel of the two different images, takes too long time

Tags: android, image-processing

I want to compare the pixel of the two different images. I am comparing the pixel of first image with all the pixels of the second Image. Here is my code stuff:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.getWidth(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.getHeight(); j++) {

        for (int k = 0 ; k<bitmpa2.getWidth(); k++) {
            for (int l = 0 ; l<bitmpa2.getHeight(); l++) {

                if (bitmap.getPixel(i, j) == bitmap2.getPixel(k, l))
                  Counter++ ;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Here the value of Counter is the number of pixels that are same in both the Images. The problem is that this works but it takes much time to perform it, so time constraint is the problem here, So what can I have to reduce the time and get exact result. Any other possibility is welcome.

Comment: Do the images have same dimensions and orientation?

Comment: @Ruel yes, images have same dimension .

Comment: Is there any possibility to get a pointer to the raw bitmap buffer in android? If so you can get a 32- time speedup by comparing the 32-bit integers of the two buffers, and only if they differ, then zoom in to the bit-unpacking that bitmap.getPixel() is doing? You will also have to take care of boundary if the bitmap width is not an integer multiple of 32.

Comment: @ Dov Grobgeld  : i dont exactly understand your point .can you please elaborate it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using API level 12 or above, there's a method called [`sameAs`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) on `Bitmap` to do exactly what you're looking for. Otherwise, use [`getPixels`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and do something like:

```
int width = bitmap1.getWidth();
int height = bitmap1.getHeight();
int pixelCount = width * height;
int[] pixels1 = new int[pixelCount];
int[] pixels2 = new int[pixelCount];

bitmap1.getPixels(pixels1, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
bitmap2.getPixels(pixels2, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);

for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; i++) {
    if (pixels1[i] != pixels2[i]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Or if you really want to do the counter thing to see how many pixels are the same, go ahead and do that.

Actually, you can probably do something with the buffers too... Maybe something like

```
int width = bitmap1.getWidth();
int height = bitmap1.getHeight();
int pixelCount = width * height;
IntBuffer buffer1 = IntBuffer.allocate(pixelCount);
IntBuffer buffer2 = IntBuffer.allocate(pixelCount);
bitmap1.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer1);
bitmap2.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer2);
int result = buffer1.compareTo(buffer2);
```

I'm not sure how those two methods compare in performance, but it's something to play around with if you want.

Comment: Your getPixels calls will fail as written, stride has to be >= width.

Comment: hey my prob is that i want to get compare % like 100 pixel both have then how many pixel match or un-match ( i.e. 85% or 85 pixels are same ) this is what i want please help

Answer (score 3):

Oh no, remember this in mind when you do image processing in Android.

> Never use getPixel() or setPixel() continuously, like a loop, it will
>   result in a really really bad performance, damn slow. Use getPixels()
>   and setPixels() instead

Well, keep in mind that you need to read Android Documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

The order of your algorithm is n^4.

I guess that you could drive that down to n^3 if you

1. loop over all possible colors.
2. inside that loop, loop on each image
3. find the occurances of color ***i*** in each image
4. finally use an equation to increment `Counter`

If color ***i*** occurs ***x*** times in `bitmap` and ***y*** times in `bitmap2`,

`Counter = Counter + x*y`