# covert array pixel from image to color to compare

Tags: android, image, imageview, getpixel

I am using the code below to get pixel by supplying the bitmap

```
public int[] foo(Bitmap bitmapFoo) {
    int[] pixels;
  //  Bitmap bitmapFoo ;            
    int height = bitmapFoo.getHeight();
    int width = bitmapFoo.getWidth();

    pixels = new int[height * width];

    bitmapFoo.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 1, 1, width - 1, height - 1); 
   return pixels;

}
```

now how do I compare it to similar image??

```
                           int[] i = foo(img2);
                int[] i2 = foo(img1);

                if (i==i2) {

                    txt.setText("same");
                }else{


                    txt.setText("different");
                }
```

Even if the image is similar not same it still shows different .How to avoid it ??

Is the comparison correct ?? or I am doing something wrong ??

Comment: What's the output if you use the same image for `i` and `i2`? Also, use `if (Arrays.equals(i, i2)) {... }`.

Comment: Hello Vikram.Is the approach correct so far?? Trying your suggestion.

Comment: Still getting different .Am I suppose to get difference and check percentage match or something ??

Comment: Also how to convert this to colour code Like get alpha,green,blue,red from the int array i ??

Comment: You might find the answer here: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817248/compare-the-pixel-of-the-two-different-images-takes-too-long-time). For getting the color from a pixel: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7807442/2558882).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are comparing objects. When you create two objects independently they are not equal.

If you have `i.equals(i2)` instead it should work as intended.

.equals compares values rather than testing to see if the objects are actually the same object

EDIT: I forgot that you may have to override .equals to achieve the desired result. 
This question may help you. 
[Why do we have to override the equals() method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175109/equals-method-in-java)

Comment: I tried that too but its still different if (i.equals(i2)) {
     
     t.setText("same");
    }else{
     

     t.setText("different");
    }